# How to test a Contivo map where there is java component involved?

Tags: java, mapping, contivo

I am using Contivo 3.11 to do mapping between 2 XML documents. For one element I am calling a Java utility to do the conversion. I am told that the utility is fine, but I need to test the entire mapping, and I do not know where to place the utility so that I can test it.

Mapping rule:

```
If Source Exists
   Call "my.package.MyClass.myMethod" Source to Target with java
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways that this could be done.

**If you have a compiled `.class` file:** Place the `.class` file under `<Contivo install dir>\domTransforms`. This particular directory is added to Contivo's Classpath, and hence your `.class` should be picked up.

**If you have a `.jar` bundle:** It really doesn't matter where you put the `.jar` file, but I would suggest to put it under `<Contivo install dir>\lib` for consistency. You will have to edit the `analyst.bat` file to manually add the `.jar` to Contivo's classpath, which would look something like `set cp=%cp%;.\lib\YourJarName.jar`

**Word of Caution:** Contivo 3.11 runs on Java 1.5, so you have to be careful for your code compatibility. Also, the method signature is of utmost importance, the signature can't be of anything other than `public String myMethod(IContivoRuntime icr, String [] args) throws TRuntimeEngineException`

Answer (score -1):

In a location that is pointed to by your **Classpath** environment variable:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Contivo doesn't pick up the Classpath env variable.

Comment: Sure.  But When java is executed (on a JVM) it tries to determine classpath via env variable and via -classpath argument.  From Contivo doc: when your mappings are defined, you automatically generate Java code, which must be placed on the Enterprise Gateway classpath.  There's your answer - Contivo sets classpath to it's "Enterprise Gateway Classpath".